# Downloading data from Nikon NPL 322 Total Station

Tags: software-recommendations, total-station

What software do I need to be able to download the data that I have collected using the TS?

What are the requirements and what is the procedure of downloading data from the TS on to a new PC Windows 10 without any prior Survey software?

Comment: Download the PDF? https://www.sepshop.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/NPL-322-User-Guide.pdf (page 147 >> To go to the download settings screen, press [1] or select
Download in the Communication menu.)